# Node does not check the value type in the latest version?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know there is one bug in this code, because the type of `sequenceNumber` is `uint32`, whereas the type of result of `val.event_date_time.toNumber() / (1000 * 1000)` is `float`. This `uint32` refers to [ProtoBuf.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/).

```
uiMessage.set("sequenceNumber", val.event_date_time.toNumber() / (1000 * 1000));
```

After `gulp`, the above codes becomes

```
d.set("sequenceNumber",e.event_date_time.toNumber()/1e6);
```

There is no error when those above two codes are running under Node v4.1.2. However, there is one error when the code after `gulp` running on Node v4.0.0.

> Error: Illegal value for [object Object] of type uint32: number (not an integer)
>           at Error (native)
>           at null.

It seems Node v4.0.0 do right to give this error of *"Illegal type"*. Why this code can work for Node v4.1.2?

IMO, the latest Node should give this error. Am I right?